# UI animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I have view with several components on it. I use Linear layout with vertical orientation

When user unchecks some checkbox I need to hide one EditText and other components moves up

```
edtPhone.setEnabled(false);
```

works well, but everything happens immediately and i want to do it slowly and animated

How can i do it in android?

Comment: HI user, Refer My Blog, i had gave Detailed Explanation There [Link](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/performing-animation-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html), assign an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to it and in `onAnimationEnd()` you should set the visibility of your `EditText` to `View.GONE` (or `View.INVISIBLE`, it depends on your needs) and do whatever you want when the animation has stopped.

Remember to assign the `TranslateAnimation` to the other components that should move up. In order to get your `TranslateAnimation` to move slowly, use `android:duration` in XML or [`Animation.setDuration()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setDuration%28long%29) in code, with a defined value in milliseconds (maybe 500 milliseconds?).